# Picasso cache exception

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am using picasso to upload images inside a recyclerView

On opening the app for the first time it works and the images are uploaded but from now on each time i open the app the load fail with a long exception regarding cache:

> ===============BEGIN PICASSO STATS ===============
>       Memory Cache Stats
>       Max Cache Size: 9586980
>       Cache Size: 0
>       Cache % Full: 0
>       Cache Hits: 0
>       Cache Misses: 1
>       Network Stats
>       Download Count: 0
>       Total Download Size: 0
>       Average Download Size: 0
>       Bitmap Stats
>       Total Bitmaps Decoded: 0
>       Total Bitmap Size: 0
>       Total Transformed Bitmaps: 0
>       Total Transformed Bitmap Size: 0
>       Average Bitmap Size: 0
>       Average Transformed Bitmap Size: 0
>       ===============END PICASSO STATS ===============

The thing is that i barely even started loading images so its totally un reasonable that the cache is already full or give exceptions

This is my code:

```
Picasso.Listener listener = new Picasso.Listener() {
@Override
public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
    Log.e(Utils.TAG, "Error loading image: " + exception.getMessage());
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
};
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
builder.listener(listener);
if(!veediChannelArrayList.get(i).isthumbLoaded()) {

     builder.build().load(veediChannelArrayList.get(i).getRegularThumbnailURL()).into(target);
```

}

```
Target target = new Target() {
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

    veediChannelArrayList.get(i).setBitMap(bitmap);
    veediChannelArrayList.get(i).setIsthumbLoaded(true);
    channelsViewHolder.thumnailIV.setImageBitmap(veediChannelArrayList.get(i).getBitMap());
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In function `into(Target target)`, Picasso checks if the current thread is main thread. Please see the code in `RequestCreate.java`:

```
public void into(@NonNull Target target) {
    long started = System.nanoTime();
    checkMain();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/305

The link above discusses the issue in more depth a potential solution.

What worked for me was `skipMemoryCache()` now known as `memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)` as `skipMemoryCache()` is deprecated.

Although this was successful at reducing crashes in my app, I do wish to tell that it did take time to reload these images, naturally as there's no cache thus compromising performance.